# How could I specify that there is no order in the regex, while still checking for quanitifers

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

So the question is a bit confusing, but basically, I want to make a regex that only matches if there is atleast one [a-z] and atleast one [a-z] and an optional [0-9] with a minimum string length of 6.

When I try:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r"[a-z]+[A-Z]+[0-9]*")
```

I don't get a match for things that should, since there is an order of one or more `[a-z]` then one or ore `[A-Z]` and then an optional `[0-9]`. Whereas what I want is a non ordered regex but that still needs one or more `[a-z]` and one or more `[A-Z]` with an optional `[0-9]`.

Even when I try:

```
regex = re.compile(r"[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}"
```

It still fails because if you only have `[a-z]` or `[0-9]` and so on, the regex still matches it because there is no specification on how many of each there needs to be, but I can't seem to figure this out, without placing an order on it.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: It looks like regular expression is not the best tool for the task. Why do you want to use regex here?

Comment: @Alik its for a coding challenge, so I get some practise.

Comment: I think you are looking for 2 positive lookaheads `^(?=[a-z0-9]*[A-Z])(?=[A-Z0-9]*[a-z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}$` https://regex101.com/r/RMKmuv/1